# Using STL(Seasonal-Trend decomposition using LOESS) for Anomaly detection

Tags: python, time-series, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I am using STL to decompose my time series data in Season, trend and residual and then by
applying this(see below) on residual. I am detecting the anomaly

```
    resid_mu = resid.mean()
    resid_dev = resid.std()
    
    //anything outside lower and upper limit is anamoly
    lower = resid_mu - 3*resid_dev
    upper = resid_mu + 3*resid_dev
```

If I do this on 1 year of data it is giving a good result but now if I get new data say for 1 new day how can I use older decomposition data so that I have to process for 1 day only and not for 1 year+1 day.

Comment: What is the minimum amount of data to detect seasonality? Is one day enough?

Comment: What is the minimum amount of data to detect seasonality?
1 week 
Is one day enough?
I am getting incremental data daily.

Comment: In order to make a prediction on the next day (or the next several days), your model should consider several previous days, months or even years, depending on seasonality period. You cannot make a prediction based on a single value, you need to be based on enough values (maybe values on a year for instance) to detect the seasonal behaviours.